# chmod method in SFTPClient of sshj-0.27.0.jar is corrupting the file permissions

Tags: java, sftp, sshj

I am trying to change the permission of a file to 555 using the SFTPClient.chmod method and this seems to be corrupting the file permissions. For eg. the file permission before the execution of this method was "-rw-r--r--" and after the execution is "----r-x-wt". Is there some problem with the jar? Any help is appreciated.

PS: I have observed the same behaviour with sshj-0.30.0.jar as well.

```
import net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient;
import net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient; 

SSHClient ssh = <>; // get the SSHClient
SFTPClient sftp = ssh.newSFTPClient(); 
sftp.chmod(filename, 555);
```

Comment: Please show your code, ideally a [mre].

Comment: But I'll allow myself a wild guess: are you changing the permissions to 555 decimal? It should probably be 0555 (octal).

Comment: Yep, that's the wrong number. Add a zero in front of it.

Comment: Method expects perms as "int", so how does adding a 0 help?

Comment: Try it and see. [Explanation.](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/literals-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Decimal 555 translates to 1000101011 but we want 101101101. So, 0555 is the correct way here.